# Azure Functions - get records by attribute name

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a function app to retrieve the records from Azure SQL DB table(loan table). Function app works fine. I want to now add filters and retrieve the records based on loan record attributes ( loan id, loan amount,...). Should I create a new function for each of the attribute that I need or is there any better approach to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, use the same function.

Comment: Thank you Thiago

Comment: Hi, any update of this question?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to create new function of each attribute.

You can put the logic in the body of the function. For example, if you are using httptrigger, you can do something like this:(The below code is just an example, you can use the logic that can achieve your requirement.)

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string loan_id = req.Query["loanid"];
            string loan_amount = req.Query["loanamount"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loan_id)) {
                //Do something when dont give loan id.
            } else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loan_amount)) { 
                //DO something when dont give loan amount.
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("This is a test.");
        }
```

The example is based on C#, basically you can put the filter logic in the body of the function.